# Delete a rails relationship with an :include_blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to select a blank object and post it so that I can clear a rails relationship. By default when you POST while selected on the :include_blank entry, nothing gets posted so it doesn't delete the old relationship. So I'm trying to add a 0 id blank item to the array.

Original:

```
<%= select_f f,:config_template_id, @operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id), :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, { :label => f.object.template_kind } %>
```

Mine:

```
<%= select_f f,:config_template_id, @operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(0, ['', 0]) %>
```

I'm getting a "wrong number of arguments (3 for 5)" error though and can't figure out what I'm missing. Any pointers? (I also can't find select_f anywhere on web, I think google ignores the _ so the search is way to open ended... For rails 3 should I be using something else?)

Comment: use `:id` and `:name` argument in your select tag. `select_f` looks like a custom helper. u might u have be having it due to some plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've omitted the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th argument you were passing into your original code block. Whatever `select_f` is, it's expecting at least 5 arguments. In the original you pass the following to `select_f` *(one argument per line for clarity)*

```
f,
:config_template_id, 
@operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id), 
:id, 
:name, 
{:include_blank => true}, 
{ :label => f.object.template_kind }
```

In your new *(broken)* call you're only passing

```
f, 
:config_template_id, 
@operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(0, ['', 0])
```

Use your first method call, just replace the 3rd argument.

```
f,
:config_template_id, 
@operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(0, ['', 0])
:id, 
:name, 
{:include_blank => true}, 
{ :label => f.object.template_kind }
```

Finally, if you don't want the `:include_blank => true` to be passed, but still do want the label, just pass `nil` or `{}` to the 5th argument

```
f,
:config_template_id, 
@operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(0, ['', 0])
:id, 
:name, 
nil,
{ :label => f.object.template_kind }
```

And altogether on one line:

```
<%= select_f f, :config_template_id, @operatingsystem.config_templates.where(:template_kind_id => f.object.template_kind_id).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(0, ['', 0]), :id, :name, nil, { :label => f.object.template_kind } %>
```

I can't guarantee this works because I don't know where the API for `select_f` is or if you created it yourself. This should however nudge you in the right direction.